# Can a page inherit multiple master pages?(ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Can a page inherit multiple master pages?(ASP.NET)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No but you can use nested master pages. Here is some reference [Nested ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

A single page cannot inherit two different master pages.
If you think about it, that should be relatively obvious.  How could it be possible? What would it do?

However, one master page can inherit a second master page.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and for remarking how stupid was my answer so I could delete it :-) silly mistake, sorry and thanks man

Answer (score 3):

You can nest as many master pages as you would like.

[MSDN link on how to nest master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A single page cannot inherit two different master pages..

But, a master page **can** be based on another master page (so you have chained inheritance)..

Answer (score 0):

A single page inherits only one master page, or we can say that a single page cannot inherit two different master pages.