# ASP.Net Nested Master Pages - How Deep Can You Nest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

This is long, so please bear with me. I just want to lay out the situation as completely as possible...

Regarding master pages in ASP.Net - I know that you can nest master pages and that you can have multiple nested master pages at the same level (the top-level master as the "parent" and multiple "children", which are the first-level-nested master pages). Can you go more than one level deep in nesting master pages (to a "grandchild" nested-master) and still be able to reach up the chain to the top-level master page using the "Master.Master.Master" syntax?

The situation:
I'm working on a C# ASP.Net application. I have a three master pages: Site.master (the top-level master page for the site), SiteWizard.master (nested from Site.master), and WizardTransactionDriver.master (a master page nested from SiteWizard.master).

Relevant markup is as follows:

Site.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="RegE_BranchV3.SiteMaster" %>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div class="container body-content">    
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="WizardContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

SiteMaster.cs

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {

        #region ===== Properties ====

        public TLoginSession LoginSession { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SiteWizard.master - nested under Site.Master

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteWizard.master.cs" Inherits="RegE_BranchV3.SiteWizard" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="WizardAnswers" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="WizardQuestions" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TransactionEntry" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

AffidavitWizardText.aspx - content page linked to SiteWizard.master

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteWizard.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AffidavitWizardText.aspx.cs" Inherits="RegE_BranchV3.WebPages.AffidavitWizardText" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SiteWizard.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="WizardQuestions" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

And code-behind in AffidavitWizardText.aspx.cs:

```
namespace somenamespace
{
    public partial class AffidavitWizardText : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private TBranchSession fBranchSession;
        private IBranchCase2 fBranchCase;
        private TLoginSession fLoginSession;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Master.Master.LoginSession = TApplLib.LoadLoginSession(Session);
        }
    }
}
```

The Master.Master.LoginSession reference works just fine.

WizardTransactionDriver.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteWizard.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WizardTransactionDriver.master.cs" Inherits="RegE_BranchV3.WebPages.WizardTransactionDriver" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SiteWizard.Master" %>   <%--SiteWizard--%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="WizardQuestions" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="TransactionEntry" runat="server">
    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TransactionItem" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

I have a content page WizardTransactionText.aspx - its master page is WizardTransactionDriver.master

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/WebPages/WizardTransactionDriver.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WizardTransactionText.aspx.cs" Inherits="RegE_BranchV3.WebPages.WizardTransactionText" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TransactionItem" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

WizardTransactionText.aspx.cs - the content-page code-behind:

```
namespace somenamespace
{
    public partial class WizardTransactionText : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private TBranchSession fBranchSession;
        private IBranchCase2 fBranchCase;
        private TLoginSession fLoginSession;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Master.Master.Master.LoginSession = TApplLib.LoadLoginSession(Session);
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio does not recognize the Master.Master.Master.LoginSession reference above and gives me an error. It recognizes the Master.Master.LoginSession reference in the higher level content page AffidavitWizardText that is bound to SiteWizard.master at the first level of master-page-nesting. Why doesn't it recognize a nested-nested reference? Is there a limit to how many levels (how deep) you can nest master pages?

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961775/can-a-page-inherit-multiple-master-pagesasp-net), bkaid says "you can nest as many master pages as you like". That can be taken a couple of ways. The example in the article he links to only shows one level of nesting of master pages. Every article and example I've seen only shows one level of master page nesting. Is there something behind the scenes that limits the number of levels that the code recognizes, even though I can create multiple levels of nested master pages when adding items in the Solution Explorer? We don't have a great deal of ASP.net experience here - is there another issue we're missing, or another path to doing this?

Thanks for any help and insight!

Comment: I don't really understand why (according to you) `Master.Master.LoginSession` is working... `MasterPage.Master` is a property of type `MasterPage` but `LoginSession` is a property from `SiteMaster`. I would expect you to cast the Master properties to their actual type in both cases.

Comment: The types are the same between the content page and the top-level master. Visual Studio recognizes it and doesn't have a problem with it - presumably due to the binding/inheritance from the content page through the nested master up to the master. It's all exposed via Intellisense. I've seen the Master.Master syntax in examples and it works to that level.

Comment: Bump... can anyone give an example of nesting master pages more than one level deep (i.e. TopMaster > MidMaster > LowMaster > LowContent)?  Thanks!

Comment: Just realized... maybe your `WizardTransactionText` just needs a `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/WebPages/WizardTransactionDriver.master" %>` directive? The concrete type of `Master` is not some magic "recognition", but if `MasterType` is declared, the `*.aspx.designer.cs` file will contain a property override with the specified type.

Comment: Good point about the VirtualPath - thanks, grek. I would have sworn that was in there. I'll give that a try as soon as I can.